# How can I set the selected row color in an Antd table in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an Ant table in React as follows:

```js
<TableAnt dataSource={mysource} columns={mycolumns}
    onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
        return {
            onClick: event => {                                
                getdetails(record);
            }, 
        };
    }}
/>
```

How can I change the color of a selected row?

Answer (score 0):

In Ant table you can change the color of the selected row by utilizing the `rowClassName` property with a conditional class name.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';

const TableSection = ({ dataSource, columns, getdetails }) => {
  const [selectedRowKey, setSelectedRowKey] = useState(null);

  const handleRowClick = (record) => {
    setSelectedRowKey(record.key);
    getdetails(record);
  };

  const rowClassName = (record) => {
    return record.key === selectedRowKey ? 'selected-row' : '';
  };

  return (
    <Table
      dataSource={dataSource}
      columns={columns}
      onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
        return {
          onClick: (event) => {
            handleRowClick(record);
          },
        };
      }}
      rowClassName={rowClassName}
    />
  );
};

export default TableSection ;
```

CSS style for the selected row:

```
.selected-row {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

Comment: this doesnt actually work , it colors all the rows , not the one that is slected only

Answer (score 0):

Changing the background color of row will have no affect. You need to select selected row `cells` and apply the background color.

There are two ways to change background color:

**Method 1: Design Token (Recommanded)**

```
import { ConfigProvider, Table } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <ConfigProvider
            theme={{
                components: {
                    Table: {
                        rowSelectedBg: '#ba80f0'
                    }
                }
            }}
        >
            <Table
                rowSelection={{}}
                dataSource={[
                    { key: '1', name: 'Mike', age: 32, address: '10 Downing Street' },
                    { key: '2', name: 'John', age: 42, address: '10 Downing Street' }
                ]}
                columns={[
                    { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
                    { title: 'Age', dataIndex: 'age' },
                    { title: 'Address', dataIndex: 'address' }
                ]}
            />
        </ConfigProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

You can check the complete list of table design tokens in [Antd Table Design Token Section](https://ant.design/components/table#design-token)

**Method 2: CSS**

Here we use rowClassName so that styles are only applied to current table selected rows only.

`App.tsx`

```
import './style.css';

import { Table } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Table
                rowSelection={{}}
                dataSource={[
                    { key: '1', name: 'Mike', age: 32, address: '10 Downing Street' },
                    { key: '2', name: 'John', age: 42, address: '10 Downing Street' }
                ]}
                columns={[
                    { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
                    { title: 'Age', dataIndex: 'age' },
                    { title: 'Address', dataIndex: 'address' }
                ]}
                rowClassName='custom-table-row'
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

`style.css`

```css
.custom-table-row.ant-table-row-selected > .ant-table-cell{
    background-color: #ba80f0 !important;
}
```

Comment: The first option using ConfigProvider does nothing, the second seems to put checkboixes, but when i slect a row , it selects all and changes all the rows to the color.

Comment: Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reverent-https-82d3sx). It's working fine. Can you create a code sandbox? Please verify the logic for rows selection.

Comment: Yes works in codesandbox, but i wasnt looking at having a checkbox , just on a row click

Answer (score 0):

**This can be done by changing the style of the row and cell of the table & it worked for me!**

```
 <Table
            dataSource={rowsWithButtonAction}
            columns={columns.map((col) => ({
              ...col,
              sorter: col.sorter || false, // Add sorter property to enable sorting
            }))}
            pagination={false}
            onRow={onRow}
            **rowClassName={rowClassName}**
            onChange={handlePageChange}
            style={{
              marginBottom: "10px",
            }}
            scroll={{ y: `calc(100vh - 300px)` }}
            loading={loading}
          />
```

First give **rowClassName** prop to the table component

And in that, you should assign your **className** to that row I have assigned **selected-row**

```
const rowClassName = (record) => {
return record.userId === "id you selected"
  ? "selected-row" 
  : "";
};
```

I am changing the background color of selected-row

```
.selected-row {
  background-color: #ecf2f4;
}
```

The Antd tables apply the hovered bg-color to td as well, so I have changed the styling of td along with the whole row.

I have done it for a specifically selected row

Hope this works for you! :)